# Tefillah when marrying almana

Tags: tefilla, marriage

I've heard there exists a formal Tefilah to be said when marrying an almana where one asks mechila from the first husband who was niftar. Would someone know where this tefilah can be found as well as the source or perhaps explanation for the concept of asking such mechila.  Thank you so much.

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/11-03-11/ יש מהחכמים שאמרו, שאף שמצד הדין מותר לשאת אלמנה שלושה חודשים לאחר פטירת בעלה, עדיף שלא לשאתה, משום שמבואר בספרי הקבלה שיכולה להיות הקפדה מצד נפש הנפטר כנגד הנושא את אלמנתו, והקפדה זו עלולה לגרום סכנה לחתן או לאלמנה (שו”ת חיים שאל ב, יט, מהרש”ם ח”ב קמא). ויש שחוששים לזה, ואם מחליטים להתחתן עורכים להם תיקון מיוחד שתיקן הרש”ש כדי שיינצלו על ידו מהסכנה (רב פעלים ב, סוד ישרים א). ויש אומרים שאם יש מקום לחשש, אזי רק בתוך שנים עשר חודש מפטירתו, אבל אחר כך ודאי שאין לחשוש (עי’ נישואין כהלכתם ב, נג).

Comment: Thank you very much. For those who are makpid, does it also apply if the almana was not the first wife of the niftar?

Comment: Seems there are those including the vilna gaon who were not makpid. מנגד, יש גדולים שלא חששו לזה כלל. ומסופר על הגאון מווילנא שנשא בעצמו אלמנה בת תלמיד חכם. כיוצא בזה מובא בספר ‘בני-יששכר’ בשם המגיד ממזריץ’, שלא רק שאין לחשוש לכך שהאלמנה תינשא, אלא שאם האלמנה ראויה להינשא, כל זמן שאיננה נישאת, אין עלייה לנפש בעלה המנוח. וזאת מפני שכביכול בגללו אלמנתו נשארת בודדה ומסכנה, והדבר נזקף לחובתו.

Comment: From the Chaim Sha'al (https://hebrewbooks.org/821) it seems there is no difference in the concern if the *almana* was not the first wife of the *niftar*.